# 2 tables - trying a RIGHT UNION, to replace fields in Table 2

Tags: sql-server, union-all, right-join

2 tables - trying a RIGHT UNION, to replace fields in Table 2 but still keep all the contents of Table 2.
[image: Table1]

[image: Table 2]

Ultimately what I am trying to do is populate the tcrutm column of table 2 with the entries based on table 1 while using PartNumber and mcno to both be equal in the 2 tables.
The code attached does what I need but only returns the column of tcrutm. I would like for table 2 to fully show up with the entries populated. Do I have to recreate the table and overwrite it? I'm not sure. Or could a UNION be used?

Any help is appreciated.

```sql
SELECT InsertResults.tcrutm
--PartList.SWITEM,
--PartList.QTY,
--ItemMaster.dsca
FROM FFGD.dbo.CAMWORKS AS InsertResults
RIGHT JOIN FFGD.dbo.BAANExport AS Results ON InsertResults.PartNumber = Results.PartNumber
    AND InsertResults.mcno = Results.mcno
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code

```
SELECT T2.[PartNumber],[SWITEM],[QTY],T1.[tcrutm],T2.[mcno] 
FROM [dbo].[table_2] AS T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table_1] AS T1
    ON T2.[PartNumber] = T1.PartNumber AND T2.mcno = T1.mcn
```

If you want populate the second table use it first and use LEFT JOIN.
Or this query is equivalent using RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT T2.[PartNumber],[SWITEM],[QTY],T1.[tcrutm],T2.[mcno]
FROM [dbo].[table_1] AS T1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table_2] AS T2
    ON T1.PartNumber = T2.[PartNumber] AND T1.mcno = T2.mcno
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is the answer to your comment:

```
SELECT T2.[PartNumber],[SWITEM],[QTY],T1.[tcrutm],T2.[mcno] 
INTO [dbo].[table_results]
FROM [dbo].[table_2] AS T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table_1] AS T1
ON T2.[PartNumber] = T1.PartNumber AND T2.mcno = T1.mcno

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table_results]
```

Just add INTO [name_of_your_table] between the fields of your SELECT and FROM

Comment: It worked great! Now Do I have to insert the results into a new table in order to keep the changes or can it be written back to the original table or can a new table overwrite the original table?

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help! Worked great! Much appreciated.